# Workaround Bug in Suggested Edits After 20 Review Limit

Tags: bug, review, edits, suggested-edits, revisions-list

Normally, when you are reviewing suggested edits, and you come across one you would like to further edit, you (as the reviewer) can click on **Improve Edit** and make changes.  When you click on **Improve Edit**:

1. The Suggested Edit is accepted
2. The Suggested edit user is awarded +2 Rep
3. Your edit is added to the revisions history

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28028160/revisions Revs 3 and 4

[image: Revs 3 and 4]

Once you have completed the limit (20) of Suggested Edits, trying to view a suggested edit in a post by clicking on the link `edit(1)` will not allow you to make changes.  However, a workaround was discovered via this question: [I can edit a post even if another edit is pending (waiting for review) - is this a bug?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283974/i-can-edit-a-post-even-if-another-edit-is-pending-waiting-for-review-is-this) which is marked as [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

> But now i found out if you change the url from:
>
> `stackoverflow.com/questions/28011705/how-can-i-get-an-if-into-mysql-code`
>
> to this:
>
> `stackoverflow.com/posts/28011705/edit`
>
> I'm getting into the edit of the question without reviewing the pending edit! And additional to that the pending edit is in the edit i'm in with the URL included plus the edit summary is already filled in with the edit summary of the pending edit.

Further testing revealed that if I as a 2k+ user use this workaround, the suggested edit is loaded onto my screen (similar to Improve Edit).  However, if I save the edit, **the suggested edit is thrown out**, and the suggested editor is NOT given +2 rep.

See this revision history: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/27421311/revisions which I found and tested this workaround bug on:

[image: Overwrote Suggested]

Proof that the suggested edit was "Approved" by one user from the queue before I messed with it:

[image: Suggested Edit]

**Is this a bug?**

Comment: Yes totally by design. Edit by 2k user kicks out pending suggested edits on the same post.

Comment: @ShadowWizard but this is pulling down the suggested edit similar to improve button in suggested edit queue.

Answer (score 3):

The bug here is in pulling in the latest suggested edit. It shouldn't do that unless the edit has already been *approved*.

Would also be nice to see some indication that a suggested edit was pending when viewing this page.

Being able to submit an edit while a suggested edit is pending is by-design though. Suggested edits are not supposed to block edits from privileged users.

Comment: Any update on this?